# Is there a way to calculate the number of all the languages over an alphabet?

Tags: automata

Let $\Sigma = \{ a,b,c \}$ be an alphabet.

How should I calculate the number of Languages over $\Sigma$?

Comment: Note TeX "\sum" is used for sums (e.g., $\sum_{i=1}^n i$) whereas "\Sigma" should be used for a capital sigma. Also, the entirety of a TeX formula code should be between dollar tags; there's no need for a separate formula for every math symbol you write. See my edits.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edits. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's uncountable infinite.

There are the languages $\{ a^0 \}$,  $\{ a^1 \}$,  $\{ a^2 \}$,  $\{ a^3 \}$ etc., which is already countable infinite.

But the powerset of the integers is uncountable infinite. So for every set S of integers, take the language $\{ a^k: k \in S \}$ and you have an uncountable infinite set.

(The number of languages that can be defined by any algorithm is only countable infinite, so most of these uncountable many languages cannot be described in any way).